# how many 2s and 3s sum to make 15, if there are can only be 6 2s and 3s

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i was watching a basketball game. a player had scored 15 points. he did this with exactly 6 shots. the shots could only be of 2 or 3 points. i worked out intuitively that he had to shoot 3 3 point shots and 3 2 point shots to get 15 points.

but what would the proper approach be? is there a correct method for this type of thing?

Comment: linear equations

Comment: $x+y=6$ and $3x+2y = 15$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first paragraph represents a typical algebraic problem in which you are required to translate word problems from English into mathematical expressions and equations. In the first two sentences, you are given a constraint. The constraint is that the basketball player must score $15$ points with $6$ shots. The shots can take two distinct values - either the basketball player scores $2$ points or the basketball player scores $3$ points.

To rewrite this information into algebraic equations, we can define two variables. Let

$$x=\text{number of 2 point shots}$$
$$y=\text{number of 3 point shots}$$

from our constraint we know that the total number of shots is $6$. Therefore

$$x+y=6$$

and as you are also given that the basketball player scored $15$ points you may conclude this point total is a linear combination of the number of two point shots and the number of three point shots. As a two point shot has a point total of $2$ and a three point shot has a point total of $3$, we see that our second equation is
$$3x+2y = 15$$
We can then rewrite the first equation as $y=6-x$. Substituting this into the second equation forms
$$3x+2(6-x) = 15\implies x+12=15 \implies x=3$$
therefore
$$3+y=6 \implies y=3$$
so we may conclude that the basketball player took three $2$ point shots and three $3$ point shots in order to score $15$ points.

Comment: 5 three point shots is an alternate solution if you say within means in less than or equal to.

Comment: thank-you for this, very helpful. and i did mean 6 exact shots. out of curiosity how would the line `x+y=6` change if the constraint was now within 6 shots. would it be `x+y<=6` but how would you then do the substitution/algebraic manipulations?

Comment: Then you would need to solve
$$x+y <= 6\tag{1}$$
$$2x+3y = 15\tag{2}$$
I would first rewrite equation $(2)$ as $y=\dfrac13(15-2x)$. Inserting this new equation into $(1)$ and simplifying produces $x \le 3$. So, we know that $0\le x \le 3$. We could also go back to equation $(2)$ and solve for $x$. This produces $x = -\dfrac32 (y - 5)$. Substituting this into $(1)$ and simplifying produces $y \ge 3$. So, we know that $3\le y \le 5$ (since $3\times 5= 15$). From here, I would test the values of $x$ where $0\le x \le 3$ and $y$ where $3\le y \le 5$.